# Android Image view stretch issue

Tags: java, android, image, picasso, android-glide

I am working on a project. in that, I have used `ImageView` to show an image from web URL as well as local. in that image not show properly. I have tried to change its scale property for `fitXY`, center crop but not working properly.

It is possible to change image height and width as per my `ImageView` height and width without effect image quality . or any other way to fix that.

Comment: try setting your imageview as follows     
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try adjustViewBounds.

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ImageView Scale Type here is some visual guidence. 
[Click Here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

If you facing problem with getting Image from web URL
Use Picasso Library. To install picasso: 
Add this in your dependency in your Gradle file:`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

For loading Image from the web:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

set property `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in imageview